# KDE splash screen picture size change

Tags: kde, plasma

I would like to change my splash screen image in KDE/PLASMA.

I made a custom theme, and changed the picture located in

```
/usr/share/plasma/look-and-feel/org.kde.my_theme.desktop/contents/splash/images/kde.svgz
```

I would like to change the size of the picture though. This should be controlled in the file:

```
/usr/share/plasma/look-and-feel/org.kde.arch_custom.desktop/contents/splash/Splash.qml
```

which reads

```
Rectangle {
    id: topRect
     width:  parent.width
     height: (root.height / 3) - bottomRect.height - 1
    y: root.height
    color: "#4C000000"
    Image {
        source: "images/kde.svgz"
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        sourceSize.height: 128
        sourceSize.width: 128
    }
}
```

I have tried to edit different parts of this, but the picture is always the same. What should I edit to change the splash image size?

Answer (score 0):

In case you (or people following the search result) were in fact trying to change the background image, check the source code for custom themes (some at [kde store](https://store.kde.org/browse?cat=488))

Basically you just need to replace [the top level / root element in Splash.qml]

```
Rectangle {
    id: root
    color: "black"
```

[as it is in the current default Fedora theme for instance]

with

```
Image {
    id: root
    source: "images/background.png"
```

Placing an appropriate background image in the specified location